# How is it possible to set up a 3*3 board where each index 1-9 correspond with a number on a number pad?

Tags: python

I can notice that the following code can be used in jupyter, but it doesn't work in other IDEs.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

def display_board(board):

  clear_output()  # Remember, this only works in jupyter!

    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')
```

I wrote the following code to draw a board in pycharm, but I don't know how I can index each square in the board with a number 1 to 9.

```
def TikBoard():

    board = ''
    a = board.join(' -------' * 3)
    b = board.join('|' + '       ' + '|' + '       ' + '|' + '       ' + '|')
    c = board.join('|' + '       ' + '|' + '       ' + '|' + '       ' + '|')
    print('\n'.join((a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a)))

TikBoard()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def TikBoard():

    board = ''
    a = board.join(' -------' * 3)
    b = lambda x,y,z:board.join('|' + x.center(7,' ') + '|' + y.center(7,' ') + '|' + z.center(7,' ') + '|')
    c = board.join('|' + '       ' + '|' + '       ' + '|' + '       ' + '|')
    print('\n'.join((a, b(*list('987')), c, a, b(*list('654')), c, a, b(*list('321')), c, a)))

TikBoard()
```

Output:

```
 ------- ------- -------
|   9   |   8   |   7   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|   6   |   5   |   4   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
|   3   |   2   |   1   |
|       |       |       |
 ------- ------- -------
```

Comment: I considered your code. Unfortunately, it doesn't index the numbers. It only prints the numbers in the squares

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
The following code can be used in order to index

```
def tik_board(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print('   |   |')
        print(' ' + arg[7] + ' | ' + arg[8] + ' | ' + arg[9])
        print('   |   |')
        print('-----------')
        print('   |   |')
        print(' ' + arg[4] + ' | ' + arg[5] + ' | ' + arg[6])
        print('   |   |')
        print('-----------')
        print('   |   |')
        print(' ' + arg[1] + ' | ' + arg[2] + ' | ' + arg[3])
        print('   |   |')
```

And in order to test the indexing. We can try this:

```
test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']
tik_board(test_board)
```